# PHP/MySQL Query/Loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have a database having the following structure:

```html
<table border="2">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>numbering</td>
          <td>country</td>
          <td>operator</td>
          <td>rate</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>12345</td>
          <td>country1</td>
          <td>operator1</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>12345</td>
          <td>country1</td>
          <td>operator1</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>12345</td>
          <td>country1</td>
          <td>operator1</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>12345</td>
          <td>country1</td>
          <td>operator2</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>12345</td>
          <td>country1</td>
          <td>operator2</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>12345</td>
          <td>country1</td>
          <td>operator2</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am first querying the operators based on the country selected by the user, and display them, however I also want to display the corresponding set of numbering for each operator. This is the code I implemented so far :

```php
<?php
    $operator_rates= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT operator, rate FROM database WHERE country='$_GET[country]'");
            foreach ( $operator_rates as $operator_rate ) {
                $numbering = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT numbering FROM database");
                echo '
                <strong>'.$operator_rate->operator.'</strong><br/>'.$numbering;
            } ?>
```

The Result I am getting is as per the below:

**Operator 1**
Array
**Operator 2**
Array
**Operator 3**
Array

The result I am expecting is having each operator and exactly underneath it the set of numbering for each operator:

**Operator 1**
12345, 12345, 12345, 12345

**Operator 2**
12345, 12345, 12345, 12345

**Operator 3**
12345, 12345, 12345, 12345

Comment: Your actual output is?

Comment: Sorry guys for some reason the image didn't upload, I have made some text replicating the output

Comment: **WARNING**: You've created a dangerous [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) by putting `$_GET` data directly in your query. **NEVER** do this. Instead, use the WordPress [prepared statements feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to properly escape all data parameters.

Comment: I think that in your second query you need to specify a where = operator. That said if the second query does result more then one row you need to loop that too

Comment: @MarcoMura it will definitely have more than one result as there is multiple operators having different numbering attached to them

Comment: Have you tried outputting the arrays you're getting to see what they contain? (with print_r or var_dump)

Comment: @mario.borg then loop the second result =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$numbering` is an array, because you are using `$wpdb->get_results` so you need to use `join` on that like this.

```
foreach ($operator_rates as $operator_rate) {
    $numbering = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT numbering FROM melitawordpress.prepaid_telephony_rates");
    echo '
                <strong>' . $operator_rate->operator . '</strong><br/>';
    $numbers = array();
    foreach ($numbering as $number) {
        $numbers[] = $number->numbering;
    }
    echo join(", ", $numbers) . "<br />";
}
```

EDIT: `$wpdb->get_results` returns with objects.

Comment: This gave me the following error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in //directory on line 87

Comment: Seems to be getting there however I got this error: Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in //directory on line 91

Comment: Oh my fault. I forgot to add it as an array the $numbers. I've editet my code. Added the `[]` after the variable name to add it as a new element.

Comment: for some reason its now breaking the code as only white page is loading. It seems the error is being caused for the array creation downwards as when I removed that part it works fine.

Comment: Inside the loop, comment out this: `$numbers[] = $number->numbering;` and say: `var_dump($number)` Please show the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67107/discussion-between-mario-borg-and-lolka-bolka).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning multiple rows.

And array is getting printed, so its showing `Array`.

You need to get formatted string by concatenating array elements with comma `,`.

Use [group_contact()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

IN

```
$numbering = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(numbering SEPARATOR ', ') AS numbering
FROM melitawordpress.prepaid_telephony_rates");
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
$numbering = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT numbering FROM database", ARRAY_A);
```

and change this line

```
<strong>'.$operator_rate->operator.'</strong><br/>'.$numbering;
```

with this

```
<strong>'.$operator_rate->operator.'</strong><br/>'.implode(',', $numbering['numbering']);
```

Comment: This is only picking up the first number attached to one operator and replicates the same value with every operator. I want to show the set of numbers attached to one operator and then show the second set of numbers attached to the second operator

Comment: I have added the answer try the below one

Comment: implementing the second option gave me the following error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in //directory on line 87

Comment: i have edit the answer again  now try it, it should work fine

Comment: this is breaking the code, notting is loading up when i implemented your solution just white page

Comment: you php code breaking somewhere inspect your code and remove the glitches and then try or do small change `implode(',', $numbering);` with this `implode(',', $numbering['numbering']);`

Answer (score 0):

Use implode function, e.g

```
foreach ($operator_rates as $operator_rate) {
$numbering = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT numbering FROM melitawordpress.prepaid_telephony_rates");
echo '
            <strong>' . $operator_rate->operator . '</strong><br/>';
echo implode(", ", $numbering) . "<br />";
```

}